# AngularJS Token Based Authentication through $http services

Tags: angularjs

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/` This is My API endpoint, where i can apply `POST` method

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/` And this is my Login endpoint, where if i submit username and passwords, in response, it returns me an API token, after i login in endpoint, i can manually apply `POST` method, i mean, i can create contact

but the problem with AngularJS apps.

I have create two form, one is `login` and another is `add contact`

for login, i write this

```
$scope.onLogin = function () {
        $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/', $scope.loginModel)
        .then(function(response) {
         //
        }, function(response) {
          //
        })
    };
```

Above snippet is works nice for login

But i want when i logged in through this form, then i should create/post new contact through `add contact` form.

and for this, i write this code:

```
$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
        .then(function(response) {
            //
        }, function(response){
            //
        });
```

I am not getting how i can implement this, i want when a user successfully logged in, only the logged in user can use `Add Contact` Form and they can successfully create/post contact on this form.

I read some Stackoverflow problems and i got i have to add token header in $http post method but not getting how to implement this. even i read angularJS official documentation, but no luck yet to get it done

Can anyone help me to implement this?

Comment: You can add the token in headers parameter and send it in post call like authorization- `$http.post('url/someapi', data, {
    headers: {'Authorization': <token here>}
});`

Comment: How can it will get the token in <token here>?

Comment: I just put it manually

Comment: you can have the token value in a variable and use the variable in <token here>